# Replace all text matched except in alt or href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace all matched text with another text, but I don't want replace if that text is in the `alt` or `href` attribute.
Example:

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
<p><img src="hello.jpg" alt="Hello"/></p>
Hello
```

My code:

```
var replacepattern = new RegExp('Hello', 'gi');
newcontent = newcontent.replace(replacepattern, function(match, contents, offset, s) {
var link = 'demo.com'
    index++;
    if (link != '') {
        return '<a href="' + link + '">' + match + '</a>';
    } else {
        return match;
    }
});
```

It works perfect with text only. How can I match text except `img src`, `alt` etc?

Comment: By "etc." do you mean ANY html attribute?

Comment: You will have to use an HTML parser, not regular expressions to be really sure I would think.

Comment: @Blazemonger yes, replace in text, not attributes

Comment: Hey! i found the solution. Use this regex:
`new RegExp('hello(?![^<]*>)',"gi");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery itself to help you with the replacement:

```
$(html)
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 1 || this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function() {
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(replacepattern, 'whatever');
    });
```

Note that the last occurrence of `Hello` is not replaced, because it's technically invalid to have a text node as a child of `<body>`.

Also, you would have to modify it to work in IE < 9 or 10; basically the browser is expected to support `node.textContent` :)

**Update**

The problem was slightly more complicated; or maybe my mind is making it more difficult than it is. Replacing text nodes with jQuery ain't the easiest to do, so some pure JS is required for that:

```
$('<div><p>Hello world!</p><p><img src="hello.jpg" alt="Hello"/></p>Hello</div>')
  .find('*')
  .andSelf()
  .each(function() {
    for (var i = 0, nodes = this.childNodes, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
      if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        var txt = nodes[i].textContent || nodes[i].innerText,
            newtxt = txt.replace(/Hello/g, 'Bye');
        if (txt != newtxt) {
          var txtnode = document.createTextNode(newtxt);
          this.replaceChild(txtnode, nodes[i]);
        }
      }
    }
})
  .end()
  .end()
  .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, i tried your code, but after replace, img tag has been removed. Any idea?

Comment: try add a div wrapper like this:
`<div><p>Hello world!</p>
<p><img src="hello.jpg" alt="Hello"/></p>
Hello`</div>
i think problem occured when node not in the same level.

Comment: thanks @Jack so much!
i found a solution by using this regex: `new RegExp('hello(?![^<]*>)',"gi")`
But your way is a good one.