# Greek fonts for Katex

Tags: javascript, fonts, mathjax, katex

I suceeded to use katex on my blog instead of MathJax. However some of the equations contained greek symbols and Katex does not contain the fonts for rendering the greek characters.
(Matjax is very good at rendering the greek letters) 
 Are there Katex fonts available to render an equation that contains greek characters? How to use these fonts (how to include them together with the Katex script on my site)?

For example the equation

```
hν0=hν+Ek+W(1)
```

(ν is \nu) is rendering good with mathjax but not with Katex.

Comment: KaTeX is an open source project with a github issue tracker, the right place to ask this first is there, not here. If you already have, link to your question there, but if you haven't: help open source by asking the people who run the project about a problem with their project. https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/issues - with that said, using proper LaTeX syntax, this looks just fine to me: http://imgur.com/6tW9D4Q

Comment: I said, in the equation is the ν symbol (not \nu). So I cannot render greek ν with katex.

Comment: in your post you say `v is \nu`, which is confiusing. Is it `v`, the ASCII letter, is it the actual Greek letter nu (the unicode letter), or is it the LaTeX command `\nu`? Because if you control the content, you control what the function uses, so you can quite easily just use the correct LaTeX syntax.

Comment: My original post has been edited. .Initially the equation was hν0=hν+W(1) containing the greek letter ν.

Comment: Fair enough, but then don't say "v is \nu", because that `\nu` means something in LaTeX context, and to people who know LaTeX, that statement is clearly not true: there is no `\nu` in your LaTeX formula. In the future, it's worth being a little more careful and saying something like "Note that this formula uses unicode: the letters "v" are Greek letters 'nu' (u+03BD), not Latin letters 'v' (U+0076)". And then on an even more technical note: LaTeX itself will fail on this formula too, unless you explicitly tell it to use the `inputenc` package. XeLaTeX *will* work, but KaTeX only ports LaTeX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different formulae-rendering js libs behave in one of 3 different ways:

- process `\pi` and tolerate `π​`​ (MathJax; MathQuill, although the result is somewhat different)
- process `\pi` but don't tolerate `π​`​ (jsMath, KaTeX)
- don't process `\pi` and tolerate `π​`​ (jqMath)

Unfortunately, like Ben has answered, KaTeX is not the one that tolerates raw greek characters. However, you may try to do some pre-parsing to "fix" this in a manner like this: before

```
<script>renderMathInElement(document.body,{delimiters:
  [{left: "$", right: "$", display: false}]
});</script>
```

add some "replace" stuff like desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474497/replace-text-in-a-website) (replace `π` with `\pi` and so on), although you should modify `replaceTextOnPage` function proposed there to replace all greek letters at once rather than launch a copy of `replaceTextOnPage` many times. You can do some other optimization since the solution there is somewhat general purpose but you know where to expect formulae on you pages.

Comment: Yes Yakovl, thank you.Though katex does accept greek fonts using this scrpt here github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/410/files, by kevinbarabash. I just do not know how to use it, yet togehter with your script.

Comment: @user36636 well, this is not a separate script, this is work-in-progress change to KaTeX itself which will probably be merged at some point. Since the last activity there was in Jan, may be it's worth asking about the state of affairs at https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/410 . Alternatively, you could change the files yourself and test that stuff, but for the changes to get applied to your blog, you need to have the lib on your site, instead of including it from outside.

Answer (score 1):

KaTeX doesn't currently support Greek letters as input, though as the comment says, `\nu` does work. See this issue for more details: [Symbol unicode replacement doesn’t work](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/issues/243)