# Convert semicolons (.,) into a certain link

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

To convert semicolons (.,) into a certain link, or any particular text to a specific link.
I hope you can understand me since I am using the translator.

For example this text is like this:

> Hello world, how are you all?.

and I would like that by means of Javascript or CSS or with what you can to the text it will automatically generate a link to the semicolons.
Example how it should look:

> Hello world[,](https://google.com) how are you all?[.](https://google.com)

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Your English is fine, but the question still makes no sense. What does it mean to convert semicolon to a link? BTW, semicolon is `;`, `.,` is period followed by comma.

Comment: the idea is to convert / generate all "." And "," from the page to a specific link.

Comment: Edit the question and show an example of the original text and the desired HTML.

Comment: I want all the commas and periods to have a link to a page.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar for your patience, I'm sorry to be so clumsy = (

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing every instance of a comma or period with an html `<a>` tag containing your url. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474497/replace-text-in-a-website) explains a good format of replacing text in a webpage, shown below. In your case, you would want to use two commands (after defining a function similar to the one below). First, `replaceTextOnPage('.', '<a>your link here</a>');` and second `replaceTextOnPage(',', '<a>your link here</a>');`. Thus, you would replace every comma `(,)` with one link, and every period `(.)` with another (or the same link, if you wish). I hope this helps!

```
function replaceTextOnPage(from, to){
  getAllTextNodes().forEach(function(node){
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(new RegExp(quote(from), 'g'), to);
  });

  function getAllTextNodes(){
    var result = [];

    (function scanSubTree(node){
      if(node.childNodes.length) 
        for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) 
          scanSubTree(node.childNodes[i]);
      else if(node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) 
        result.push(node);
    })(document);

    return result;
  }

  function quote(str){
    return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
  }
}
```

Comment: fantastic dguis, I will try it.