# how can i change the search button in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I want to change this text to other text:
I tried to search but I didn't find any solution
[image]

Comment: May this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474497/replace-text-in-a-website You can inject the js into your shiny app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  iris,
  options = list(
    language = list(
      search = "Seek"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: It would be good to give a bit of an explanation about why the code works.

Comment: @user438383 It suffices to follow the documentation of datatables. It works because this is the way it has been designed. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41287/faq-how-do-i-replace-the-search-label-either-the-text-or-as-a-placeholder-attribute